# Strange div behavior with .show()

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, position

i'm trying to use .toggle method (jquery) in a board.
I've set up a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnLCG/3/).
Here is the problem: when i click on the div #forum1, the div #forum3 goes on the right. I would prefer that this div goes to the bottom...

Anyone has an idea about that?

Comment: @Lght Seems to be a CSS problem - nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @Inkbug It seems... But i don't find what makes trouble... I should ask again with css tag !

Comment: @Lght Probably changing the tags would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what you'd expect from the float property? Making it longer causes free space right to put the next div, thereby moving it over there.

You can obtain the result you have in mind by putting them both in a vertical div of half the width of the page. The first would then contain the odd numbers and the second one the even.

Comment: _You can obtain the result you have in mind by putting them both in a vertical div of half the width of the page. The first would then contain the odd numbers and the second one the even._ --
And finally, the solution... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I wasn't sure if you wanted to know why it happend or how you could solve it. Glad I could help.